# FreeBSD MySQL error after installation

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I am on FreeBSD 10.2 32 bit and installed the newest version of mysql with the following command:

```
 pkg install mysql57-server-5.7.12
```

Now, when I try to start mysql:

```
 service mysql-server start
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server: WARNING: failed precmd routine for mysql
```

I am getting this error. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4):

Check your **/var/db/mysql** folder, if it contains files, make a backup and delete dir content:

```
rm -rf /var/db/mysql/*
```

Then do a data directory initialization:

```
/usr/local/libexec/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
```

You should get a new temporary password, write it down, then start mysql-server

```
service mysql-server start
```

After mysql starts, secure the installation via:

```
 /usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score -1):

Open /etc/rc.conf and append or modify this line :

```
mysql_enable="YES"
```

Save the file, close it and retry to start the server.